# Update frame before frame.tkraise()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a small app to search customer details from a db and update aspects of them using different frames to input the various catagorys of information. As each frame of info input is complete I would like to return to a resume frame to view and subsequently store the full information. My problem is that I can not get the resume frame to update with the information which I store in a dict in the controller class. frame.update() does not seem to work. What is the correct way to achieve this?
Thanks for any help.
Here is a cut down version of the code;

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk


class OrdersApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "2017 Orders")
        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, "1024x690+40+60")

        windowbox = tk.Frame(self)
        windowbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        windowbox.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        windowbox.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.shared_data = {
            "familyname": tk.StringVar(),
        }

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (Home, CustomerSelect):

        frame = F(windowbox, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.configure(background="#dcc8af")
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(Home)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

def search_by_number(self, searchnumber, cont):
    # cont is the frame to be called after function run
    print(searchnumber)  # to check input
# here data grabbed from db using user input phone number (now hard coded)
    row = 'chris'

    self.shared_data["familyname"].set(row)

    print(self.shared_data["familyname"].get() + ' SBN has run')
    # the data is stored successfult to the controler dict
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.update()
    frame.tkraise()
# this raises cont(customerdetails) but the new information from  shared_data is not updated


class Home(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.controller = controller
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Search", compound=tk.CENTER, borderwidth=3, relief="raised",
                        command=lambda: controller.search_by_number(phonenumber.get(), CustomerSelect))
    image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/buttonRed.gif")
    button1.config(image=image3, width=64, height=40)
    button1.image = image3
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    framelabel = tk.Label(self, text="Home Frame")
    framelabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

    phonelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="phone number", font=("Arial", 20), background='#dcc8af')
    phonelabel.grid(row=2, column=1)
    phonenumber = ttk.Entry(self, width=30, font=("Arial", 20))
    phonenumber.insert(0, "0468777904")
    phonenumber.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=16, pady=16)


class CustomerSelect(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.controller = controller
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    framelabel = tk.Label(self, text="Customer select Frame")
    framelabel.grid(row=0, column=3)

    familynamelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Family name", font=("Arial", 10), background='#dcc8af')
    familynamelabel.grid(row=1, column=2)
    familyname = ttk.Entry(self, width=20, font=("Arial", 10))
    fn = self.controller.shared_data["familyname"].get()
    familyname.insert(0, fn)
    familyname.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=4, pady=8)


app = OrdersApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have provided way more code than is needed to review your problem. Also you need to provide your imports and now you are calling your class as those are relevant to making sure your code is not missing anything.

Comment: thanks for the tip - I'm rather inexperienced (and old) I followed the link and have made I hope a better stab at presenting the code. It runs without errors, but the familyname ttk Entry widget does not seem to receive the data?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code other than indentation.  This is a simple example, using 2 classes, that shows how to update the Entry from either one by calling the update function in the second class.  Note that part of the purpose of a class is to contain all of the methods that pertain to a specific function of the code, i.e. the class creates the widgets it uses and updates its Entry widget in this simple example.

```
class OrdersApp():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.frames = {}

        CS_instance=CustomerSelect(self.master)

        ## dictionaryy will only have one entry because there
        ## is only one other class in this example 
        self.frames["CustomerSelect"]=CS_instance

        ## test = wait for 5 seconds and change entry
        self.master.after(5000, self.change_entry)

    def change_entry(self):
        """ change the Entry widget from this class
            by calling function in other class
        """
        self.frames["CustomerSelect"].update_entry("From OrdersApp  ")

class CustomerSelect():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        fr=tk.Frame(parent)
        fr.grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Label(fr, text="Customer select Frame").grid(row=0, column=3)

        tk.Label(fr, text=" Family name ", font=("Arial", 10),
                 background='#dcc8af').grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.familyname = tk.Entry(fr, width=50, font=("Arial", 10))
        self.familyname.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=4, pady=8)

        ## initial text
        self.update_entry("From CustomerSelect")

    def update_entry(self, new_text):
        self.familyname.insert(0, new_text)

master=tk.Tk()
OA=OrdersApp(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I don't seem to be able to get this code to run either on it's own (I imported Tkinter first) or by replacing the classes in my example. In both cases I get the console error

line 10, in __init__
CS_instance=CustomerSelect(self.master)
NameError: name 'CustomerSelect' is not defined

what am I missing?

Comment: It runs fine for me using "import tkinter as tk".  I do not see any way that line 10 can be "CS_instance=CustomerSelect(self.master) " for the example that I posted.  Check the spelling on the class definition and make sure it is spelled the same, and that it is not indented under some other code.   Other than that, post the code that you are running with the complete error message.